# How to take a C++ project from CLion and move it over to QT Creator?

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface, qt-creator, clion

I have been working on a personal project throughout college that has incorporating new skills as I learn them. This project has been done solely in CLion which is the IDE my school uses and is the only one I am familiar with.

I am now at the point where I want to learn QT to be able to create a GUI and take the next step with my project. After trying to integrate QT into CLion, I realized it is just too difficult and I am better off using QT creator.

I am struggling with figuring out how to take my code from CLion and essentially port it over to QT Creator. All of the examples from the QT documentation only cover simplistic programs as examples and I can't find anything to support building a QT project with multiple classes.

My project is a simple casino program. Currently have the Blackjack and Three Card Poker games fully completed. The program consists of the following classes

```
Main.cpp 
Card.cpp 
Deck.cpp 
Player.cpp
Dealer.cpp 
Blackjack.cpp 
ThreeCardPoker.cpp
```

To further show what I am looking to do with QT creator which will hopefully allow you to point me to where I can figure out how to start this.

```
// Very simple and has the player select which game they want to play 
Main.cpp
// Using Blackjack as the example to show what needs to be accomplished with QT Creator 
// When Called, it creates a Player Object and gets Name/Balance, a Deck object which is a vector // the Card Object. Then the gameplay loop begings
Blackjack.cpp
```

I am hoping someone can point me where to go to get started with QT Creator when I am starting with a project that is already completed.

Comment: One method would be to stick with CMake and use the same CMakeLists.txt you have with CLion with Qt-Creator.

Comment: If you _only_ want a GUI there are many leaner alternatives to Qt. Qt is dangerous as it uses so many custom stuff like QStrings over std:: implementations. If you start a project with Qt, you're pretty much stuck with it, which is a very bad thing. Depending on what you wanna do - there is FLTK, wxwidgets, ImGui...

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure you know CLion doesn't have a designer the same way Qt Creator does. The way Qt Creator's designer works is by creating a header file at compile time from the .ui that you would interface with, called "ui_[name].h". The way CLion encourages you to do it is just by interfacing with every single widget/item explicitly (what the ui header does, but coded by hand). As far as I know, there is not a way to "convert" the C++ code into a .ui, but doing it by hand is usually not too difficult.

The IDE does not care how you have your UI code stored. It only cares that it's syntactically correct and can be linked, the same as any other piece of code you would use with the IDE. Both should work in either IDE, as long as you have a way to edit the .ui files (not guaranteed) and the Qt build process is respected.

Otherwise, there should not need to be any "porting" done, given your CMakeLists.txt or .pro file look as they should, you have a proper kit set up, etc.

Answer (score 0):

If your project has no external dependencies then using your project is simple:

1. Create a project with QtCreator, delete the .cpp and .h files created by default.
2. Copy the .cpp and .h of your project to the project folder.
3. Right click on the name of the project and a menu will be displayed, in that menu choose "Add existing Files" and select the .cpp and .h.

Another option is:

1. Run the following command from the cmd or console:

   ```
   qmake -project /path/of/project/directory
   ```
2. Then press the "Open" button in the initial QtCreator window, look for the project folder and select the .pro

Comment: So that part I get, now how do I actually use QtCreator to create a GUI for those files now?

Comment: @NicholasTallarico For this I recommend you review the Qt tutorials, that is not so simple and an SO post does not have the space for it.